# How to use setAttribute on Symfony Form field

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add a `stripe-data` attribute to a field generated with `createBuilder`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->createBuilder(FormType::class, [
        'action' => $this->router->generate('storeSubscription', ['id' => $store->getId()]),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ])
        ->add('plan', PremiumType::class, [
            'data_class' => PremiumFeaturesEmbeddable::class,
            'data' => $store->getPremium(),
        ]);

    if (null === $store->getBranchOf()->getStripeCustomer() || null === $store->getBranchOf()->getStripeCustomer()->getDefaultSource()) {
        $form->add('credit_card', CreditCardStripeTokenType::class)
            ->add('company_data', CompanyType::class, [
                'data_class' => Company::class,
                'data' => $store->getBranchOf()
            ]);

        // Remove unused data
        $form->get('company_data')
            ->remove('brand')
            ->remove('primaryEmail')
            ->remove('description')
            ->remove('phoneNumber')
            ->remove('faxNumber')
            ->remove('save');

        // Set data-stripe
        $form->get('company_data')
            ->get('legalName')->setAttributes(['attr' => ['data-stripe', 'name']]);
    }
```

As you can see, the last line of this code gets the first the `copmany_data` form type, then of this gets the field `legalName`: on this I want to set the attribute `stripe-data="name"`.

But this code doesn't work.

To add the attribute I have to use `form_widget` in Twig:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_errors(form.company_data.legalName) }}
    {{ form_label(form.company_data.legalName) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.company_data.legalName, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-sm', 'data-stripe': 'name'}}) }}
</div>
```

This way it works and attribute is correctly added.
For sure, I may continue setting those attributes in Twig, but I'd like to add them in PHP but don't understand why it doesn't work. Is someone able to explain me how to solve the problem? Thank you!

**What I tried**

Test 1

```
// Set data-stripe
$form->get('company_data')
    ->get('legalName')->setAttributes(['data-stripe', 'name']);
```

Test 2

```
// Set data-stripe
$form->get('company_data')
    ->get('legalName')->setAttribute('data-stripe', 'name');
```

Test 3

```
// Set data-stripe
$form->get('company_data')
    ->get('legalName')->setAttributes(['attr' => ['data-stripe', 'name']]);
```

No one of those work. I don't know what to try more.

NOTE: I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20311) too.

Comment: You would need to use `['data-stripe' => 'name']` to set the value to name.. otherwise you are just setting 2 values.

Comment: Tried and doesn't work. I've updated the question with the test I made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need add/modify any option from any existing field, just do the following:

```
// to keep the current options
$options = $form->get('company_data')->get('legalName')->getConfig()->getOptions();

// add/change the options here
$options['attr']['data-stripe'] = 'name';

// re-define the field options
$form->get('company_data')->add('legalName', TextType::class, $options);
```

This doesn't alter the order of the fields, only change their options. Useful for conditional options on `buildForm()` and listener/suscriber events.

---

However, if you change the approach this can be achieved in another way.

First, add a new default option `'add_stripe_name' => null` to `CreditCardStripeTokenType` form type and pass this value to `'legalName'` field options definition:

```
// into CreditCardStripeTokenType::buildForm():

$legalNameOptions = array();

if ($options['add_stripe_name']) {
    $legalNameOptions['attr']['data-stripe'] = $options['add_stripe_name'];
}

$builder->add('legalName', TextType::class, $legalNameOptions)
```

So the `'add_stripe_name'` option of `CreditCardStripeTokenType` will be the flag to add the attribute to `legalName` field:

```
$builder->add('credit_card', CreditCardStripeTokenType::class, [
     'add_stripe_name' => 'name', // <---- \o/
]);
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to explain why `setAttribute()` and `setAttributes()` don't work: they are not aimed at editing the options. So it seems there is no method to edit fields' options without doing this three-lines flow. This is really un-smarty -.-' Possible there is a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Afraid not, the `FormConfigInterface` interface does not allow that, only `getOptions()`, `hasOption()` and `getOptions()` is allowed :(

Comment: I recommend another approach then, see my updated answer.

Comment: No, this approach is not usable as the `StripeCardStripeTokenType` is in another third party bundle (the bundle is wrote by myself, but anyway I don't want to couple the two things as the bundle is open source - https://github.com/Aerendir/stripe-bundle/blob/master/Form/Type/CreditCardStripeTokenType.php) So doing this, in this way, is not possible... And in the end I'm not sure losing all this time makes sense as the problem can be solved - very dirty in my opinion - via Twig...

Comment: Another approach is to pass an option to the `->add('company_data', CompanyType::class, [... , 'stripe-data' => true])` and in that form builder check for it and add or not the attribute conditionally... But anyway an `addOption()` is really smarter in my opinion as also this solution requires a lot of lines of code for the ifs, the parenthesis, to merge array etc...

Comment: Just one thing to add:
Instead of
xxxType::class
we can use 
get_class($builder->get($fieldsName)->getType()->getInnerType())
to avoid checking field type every time.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the embed form type `company_data` you specify your `attr`

```
$builder->add('legalName', TextType::class, array(
       'attr' => array('data-stripe' => 'name'),
 ));
```

Comment: No, I don't need this attribute ever set: only on specific situations. So, this is a possibility, but this makes the generated code dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second @yceruto's approach I have a little inline optimisation which I can't say is definitely more readable but saves some lines and allows you to have continuous chain of the ->add() methods invoked from the $builder:

As he mentioned, first, add a new default option `'add_stripe_name' => null` to `CreditCardStripeTokenType` form type and pass this value to `'legalName'` field options definition, using the `array_merge_recursive()` function:

```
// into CreditCardStripeTokenType::buildForm():

$builder->add('legalName', TextType::class, array_merge_recursive([], // <---- here other options are stored if any, could be empty as well
    $options['add_stripe_name'] !== null ? ['attr' => ['data-stripe' => $options['add_stripe_name']]] : []
);
```

So the `'add_stripe_name'` option of `CreditCardStripeTokenType` will be the flag to add the attribute to `legalName` field:

```
$builder->add('credit_card', CreditCardStripeTokenType::class, [
     'add_stripe_name' => 'name', // <---- \o/
]);
```